# Cumsum excluding current value

Tags: r, cumsum

I am new to R and I am trying to write a function to cumulatively sum previously ordered items by customers. I have already found an almost-fitting example of code on Stack Overflow, but I do not manage to modify it accordingly to my needs.

This is the code:

```js
Fruits <- Fruits[order(Cars$order.id), ]  #sort data
Fruits$prev_Apples<-with(Fruits, 
    ave(
        ave(Apples, customer.id, FUN=cumsum),  #get running sum per customer.id
        interaction(customer.id, order.id, drop=T), 
    FUN=max, na.rm=T) #find largest sum per index per seg
)
```

And this is the Fruits data.frame:

```html
order.id   customer.id Apples  Peaches  Pears
1001    J Car Ltd     1    0    0
1002     Som Comp     0    2    0
1005    Richardson    0    0    1
1004    J Car Ltd     1    0    0
1003    J Car Ltd     2    0    0
1006    Richardson    1    0    1
1007     Aldridge     0    0    1
1008    J Car Ltd     0    0    1
1010     Som Comp     0    1    0
1009    J Car Ltd     1     0     0
```

This is what I would like to obtain:

```html
order id customer id Apples Peaches Pears Prev_Apples
1001 J Car Ltd 1 0 0 0
1002 Som Comp 0 2 0 0
1003 J Car Ltd 2 0 0 1
1004 J Car Ltd 1 0 0 3
1005 Richardson 0 0 1 0
1006 Richardson 1 0 1 0
1007 Aldridge 0 0 1 0
1008 J Car Ltd 0 0 1 4
1009 J Car Ltd 1 0 0 4
1010 Som Comp 0 1 0 0
```

And this is what I actually get:

```html
order id customer id Apples Peaches Pears Prev_Apples
1001 J Car Ltd 1 0 0 1
1002 Som Comp 0 2 0 0
1003 J Car Ltd 2 0 0 3
1004 J Car Ltd 1 0 0 4
1005 Richardson 0 0 1 0
1006 Richardson 1 0 1 1
1007 Aldridge 0 0 1 0
1008 J Car Ltd 0 0 1 4
1009 J Car Ltd 1 0 0 5
1010 Som Comp 0 1 0 0
```

So the problem is that cumsum includes also the current order of Apples, while I would like it to include only previous orders. How should I modify the code? Any answer will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I can't really tell what's going on with your data - the spaces in the column . names make it difficult. Could you share with `dput()` so it is copy-pasteable? (And don't use snippets - they don't work with R).

Comment: Looks like you want a `cumsum` where the first term is 0 and the last term is omitted. Try `FUN = function(x) c(0, head(cumsum(x), -1))`

Comment: Thank you very much, that's indeed what I needed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the input shown reproducibly in the Note at the end we sort `Fruits` fixing the erroneous reference to `Cars` and then use `ave` with `cumsum` subtracting the current value of `Apples` from `cumsum` cancelling the last value in the sum.

This gives the same answer as the one listed as expected in the question.

```
Fruits <- Fruits[order(Fruits$order.id), ]
transform(Fruits, Prev_Apples = ave(Apples, customer.id, FUN = cumsum) - Apples)
```

giving:

```
   order.id customer.id Apples Peaches Pears Prev_Apples
1      1001   J Car Ltd      1       0     0           0
2      1002    Som Comp      0       2     0           0
5      1003   J Car Ltd      2       0     0           1
4      1004   J Car Ltd      1       0     0           3
3      1005  Richardson      0       0     1           0
6      1006  Richardson      1       0     1           0
7      1007    Aldridge      0       0     1           0
8      1008   J Car Ltd      0       0     1           4
10     1009   J Car Ltd      1       0     0           4
9      1010    Som Comp      0       1     0           0
```

**Note:** The input in reproducible form is assumed to be:

```
Fruits <- structure(list(order.id = c(1001L, 1002L, 1005L, 1004L, 1003L, 
1006L, 1007L, 1008L, 1010L, 1009L), customer.id = structure(c(2L, 
4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("Aldridge", "J Car Ltd", 
"Richardson", "Som Comp"), class = "factor"), Apples = c(1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), Peaches = c(0L, 2L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), Pears = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("order.id", "customer.id", "Apples", 
"Peaches", "Pears"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```