# Cumsum excluding some rows

Tags: r, if-statement, cumsum

I have a question linked to:
[Cumsum excluding current value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47637184/cumsum-excluding-current-value)
How to apply cumsum excluding a certain customer.id? For instance:

```
order.id   customer.id  Apples   Peaches  Pears
1001       J Car Ltd        1       0       0
1002        Som Comp        1       2       0
1005       Richardson       0       0       1
1004       J Car Ltd        1       0       0
1003       J Car Ltd        2       0       0
1006       Richardson       1       0       1
1007        Aldridge        0       0       1
1008       J Car Ltd        0       0       1
1010        Som Comp        0       1       0
```

I want to apply cumsum to keep track of previous apple orders:

```
Fruits <- Fruits[order(Fruits$order.id), ]  #sort data
Fruits$prev_Apples<-with(Fruits, 
    ave(
        ave(Apples, customer.id, FUN=function(x) c(0, head(cumsum(x), -1))),  #get running sum per customer.id
        interaction(customer.id, order.id, drop=T), 
    FUN=max, na.rm=T) #find largest sum per index per seg
)
```

But I also want to exclude from my cumsum customer.id Som Comp. For him, I want the prev_Apples column to be equal to 0:

```
order id    customer id Apples  Peaches Pears   Prev_Apples
1001      J Car Ltd         1       0       0       0
1002      Som Comp        **1**     2       0       0
1003      J Car Ltd         2       0       0       1
1004      J Car Ltd         1       0       0       3
1005      Richards          0       0       1       0
1006      Richards          1       0       1       0
1007      Aldridge          0       0       1       0
1008      J Car Ltd         0       0       1       4
1010      Som Comp          1       0       0     **0**
```

So I thought to add this line of code:

```
if(Fruits$customer id =='NULL'){
Prev_Apples = 0
return (Fruits$customer id)
}
```

But of course I get the error:
“the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used”

I understood why I get the error, but how can I avoid it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've forgotten to subtract the current value of the Apples column. After you use your code to calculate `prev_Apples` the following code should work.

```
Fruits$prev_Apples <- Fruits$prev_Apples - Fruits$Apples
Fruits[which(Fruits$customer.id == "Som Comp"), ]$prev_Apples <- 0
#   order.id customer.id Apples Peaches Pears prev_Apples
# 1     1001   J Car Ltd      1       0     0           0
# 2     1002    Som Comp      1       2     0           0
# 5     1003   J Car Ltd      2       0     0           1
# 4     1004   J Car Ltd      1       0     0           3
# 3     1005  Richardson      0       0     1           0
# 6     1006  Richardson      1       0     1           0
# 7     1007    Aldridge      0       0     1           0
# 8     1008   J Car Ltd      0       0     1           4
# 9     1010    Som Comp      0       1     0           0
```

Comment: Indeed, I forgot that. Now I edited my question, btw thank you for your correct answer!